# Any Python API to get the remaining memory of plasma?

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-plasma

I'm relatively new to plasma. Want to ask after connecting to the client using Python API `pyarrow.plasma`, is there any API to find the remaining available memory of the current plasma object store?
Seems using `client.list()` can get all objects and there is size information of each object and I can sum up... but is there any easier way?
When putting data into plasma, if the storage is full, some previous objects will be evicted and this log only appears in the console right? So when running the Python program, users would be unaware that the storage is full and some data is missing?

Hope to get some instructions on this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `client.store_capacity()`.

It's not very well [documented](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/src/plasma/client.cc#L331), but I think it retuns the total capacity of the store, so you may have to withdraw the size of each objects in the store to know what's remaining.

Comment: Hi, I checked `client.store_capacity()` and it returns the total memory I start plasma, which I already know... Is there any API to get the remaining memory, which I don't directly know... Thanks!